# Powering 3 MG996R servos

Tags: robotic-arm, arduino, servomotor, rcservo, current

I'm building a robotic arm with 3 MG996R servos using Arduino Uno R3 board. I'm using [this](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B072TCX3QP?ref_=cm_sw_r_apan_dp_QW5GADPVWWPQCRBNXX7F) 16 channel servo motor driver for the project. I'd like to use an AC-DC adapter to power the servos. Is that possible? If not what can I do?

**PS**: I'm a mechanical engineer who's got no idea about electronics (at least for now).

Comment: what else would you use for power?

Comment: technically, the module you are using is a servo motor controller with an integrated power distribution bus ... the motor driver is inside each servo motor enclosure

Comment: @jsotola what current rating should the adapter have?

Comment: the power supply should be able to source at least 10 A ... the motors have 2.5 A stall current ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=power+supply+5V+10A&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: @jsotola can I use this: https://amzn.eu/d/3g6W9ER

Comment: what voltage do the servos require?

Comment: @jsotola the operating voltage for the MG996R servo is 4.8 ~ 6.6 volts DC

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you operate the servo at 5V nominal, then it can draw up to 3A and 3A being the stall current for a typical MG996R servo.

So you need at least 9A, to account for inrush current let's add 1.6x as a safety factor to the current requirement (which is 14.4A), and hence an AC to Dc power supply of 5V @15A (Approx) should be adequate enough to run 3x MG996R servos.

The power supply in the comments section is unreasonably overkill and expensive. I would suggest going with adapters like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08764XJ2M) which are cheap and easy to find on amazon.

*Note*: Also make sure to check the max. current per channel capability on your controller board to support at least 3A draw.

Hope this answer helps in answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself a power supply as others has suggested and read https://learn.adafruit.com/16-channel-pwm-servo-driver/hooking-it-up for a guide to connecting things